# heroku not showing the Procfile file Discord.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js, worker

So I've been trying to set up my bot on Heroku so it can run 24/7 and I followed multiple tutorials but this keeps happening no matter what tutorial I follow. My problem is that in your bot folder you need to make a "Procfile.txt" with 
worker: node index.js written inside it and I've done that and its shown in git hub that the file is there and the text inside it is correct yet on Heroku when I go under the Resources Tab to disable web and enable worker its not there [this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T6S1.png) and this is whats in my git repositories [(My Repository)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIrlp.png) [(Inside the .txt file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Wpf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file should be named `Procfile` without any extension.

Comment: How do I make it have no extension?

Comment: You simply have to remove .txt from the end of the file. Someone edited my original answer, and so it wasn't as clear now. Sorry!

Comment: Seeing as you marked my answer correct, I'm assuming that worked for you :)? Let me know if it didn't.

Comment: Yeah it did thanks a lot! None of the tutorials showed how todo this XD